# Reduce Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to sum all numbers that fall under "sales" in the following dictionary:

```
{'a': {'sales': {}, 'revenue': {}}, 'b': {'sales': {}, 'revenue': {}}, 'c': {'sales': {'February2017': 6240.0, 'March2017': 8869.75, 'January2017': 15720.0}, 'revenue': {'February2017': 312.0, 'March2017': 432.4, 'January2017': 786.0}}, 'd': {'sales': {'February2017': 4184.9, 'March2017': 6181.709999999999, 'January2017': 6080.55}, 'revenue': {'February2017': 188.86, 'March2017': 292.61, 'January2017': 273.45}}}
 #
```

The output should be: 6240 + 8869.75 + 15720 + 4184.9 + 6181.7099 + 6080.55

I am able to cycle through the keys one by one and get the right answer but is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
total_sum = 0
for key,value in dict.items():
    for key_a, value_a in value['sales'].items():
        total_sum += value_a
```

For example, is there a way I can do this by using something like `reduce`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `reduce()` when you can `sum()` with a generator expression, e.g.:

```
>>> sum(sum(value['sales'].values()) for value in data.values())
47276.91
```

Or alternatively in nested form:

```
>>> sum(n for value in data.values() for n in value['sales'].values())
47276.91
```

Note: you shouldn't call your variable `dict` as it hides python's builtin `dict` type.

Comment: @Bleh You should know that this solution is hardcoded to the data you've given. If your data has the same structure, then that's okay. But if it's random and arbitrary, I urge you to look at mine.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not sure what you mean, looks like monthly sales data under the `sales` key. Recursion seems overkill for a structured data set and unnecessarily complicates the OPs question.

Comment: @AChampion Going by the fact that OP introduces random keys, it is possible to have something like `{'a': {'sales': {'random1' : 'sales' : {......} }, 'random2': { 'sales' : { .... } }}` Your approach will fail.

Comment: I'll let the OP answer that as I'm not sure where you are seeing random keys: `{'<name>': {'sales': {'<month>': <value>}, 'revenue': {'<month>': value}}}`